# Returning IList as a REST API using Linq

Tags: linq, rest, entity

I am working with REST (using WCF) from past 2 years but new to Entity Model & Linq, however have used nHibernate.

I made a simple service with folloiwng :-

NorthwindModel [A data model having Product, Order and Order_Detail tables]
ProductService exposed as REST with specific config (not using WebServiceHostFactory)

Service Contract :-

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IProductService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)
    ]
    IList<Product> GetProducts();
}
```

Service Implementation :-

```
public class ProductService : IProductService
{
    #region IProductService Members

    public IList<Product> GetProducts()
    {
        IList<Product> prodList = new List<Product>();
        NorthwindEntities ne = new NorthwindEntities();
        var query = from category in ne.Products select category;
        prodList = query.ToList<Product>();
        return prodList;
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Service Tag :-

```
<services>
  <service name="HellooData.ProductService" behaviorConfiguration="wcfJSONBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="REST" binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="HellooData.IProductService" bindingConfiguration="RESTBINDING">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" bindingConfiguration="RESTBINDING" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Binding : -

```
 <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="RESTBINDING" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"  >
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
```

After trying to call the service from the browser i get **"Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data"** error in Chrome and an empty page in Mozilla.

Have tried to debug but data is fetched properly (77 records) and returned without any exception. I somehow have a doubt in config or size of the data but not sure. Did try
to tamper the result set (only 2 instead of 77) result was still the same.

Can someone indicate what's going wrong?

Comment: Use Fiddler to check if your data are transferred or not. Are you using lazy loading?

Comment: I have done the following :- 

1) Checked the response with string data, and it works!
2) Changed the response to null and it works!
3) Made an empty response and it doesn't work!
4) Kept only one record instead of standard 77, still doesn't work.
5) Made a Data Service(which is using DataFactory) and linked with EDM, and surprisingly it works.

I somehow doubt on datatype of properties in Product Class but am not sure.

Comment: Do you use lazy loading?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue; in my case, I was disposing the database context before my SQL controller finished using it.